# Problem with .htaccess RewriteRules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this .htaccess RewriteRules, that doesn't work.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\/(.+)\/$ /index.php?pg=$1&act=$2
```

What this code should do, is transofrm `/somthing/other/` into `/index.php?pg=somthing&act=other`.

Making some test, I discovered that also the `pg` var is not passed.

I have another line like this, `RewriteRule ^(.+)\/$ /index.php?pg=$1` an it work! So, I don't know why the first one didn't work!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to use any other characters than a-z and 0-9 I recommend you to use this:

`RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)$ /index.php?pg=$1&act=$2`

It should work.

Comment: I'm not a pro of Regular expression, but, what is the ? on the end?

Comment: Me neither, but this is the way I always write the .htaccess. It's working for me, and yours too: `RewriteRule ^(.+)\/(.+)\/?$ /index.php?pg=$1&act=$2`, with that question mark

Comment: Ok, this is going crazy.. With the '?' ALL the website stop working! :|

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?pg=$1&act=$2` Works for me and it's without "?"

Comment: @Daniel let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2898/discussion-between-alberto-and-daniel)